# Can I create an instagram follow bot with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, automation, bots, laravel-dusk

I am looking to do some automation and thought an easy entry to automation might be to create a simple instagram follow bot that will log in and follow some accounts.

Can I do this with Laravel Dusk to automate going to the login page/filling in details etc or is this something I would have to do with Python for example?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/is-it-possible-to-use-laravel-dusk-browser-outside-of-testing)?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan yes something like that! might have to look into using that package a bit more. Hopefully he shows me its capable

Comment: @Alex Yes, I created a twitter bot with dusk, that logs into twitter and post current weather updates and logs out. Used Laravel-zero to accomplish this.

Comment: Nice! have you published the code anywhere? would be interested in taking a look. Always great to learn from someone who has done it before